# Is there a way to group related code modules in the MS Office VBA Editor?

Tags: vba, excel, editor

Conveniently, the VBA Editor's Project Explorer groups items by Project then by type (Excel Objects, Forms, Modules and Class Modules).

However, one of my projects makes use of a large number of objects and it's getting cumbersome to trawl through them. Is there a way to group them together, perhaps something akin to Java's Package naming convention?

Eg
 com.site.maths.geometry.shapes

Comment: no, it can't be done in Excel's VB Editor. Maybe VSTO offers something like this, or VS .NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no, it can't be done in Excel's VB Editor. Perhaps VSTO offers something like this, or VS .NET

Comment: Grrr! I thought as much. That's a lame as a snake with a broken tail!